# Не могу перебросить пользователя в другую функцию

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу простенького бота с разными минииграми (первый опыт).

```
import telebot
import config

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands= 'start')
def welcome(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте! Я - Джарвис - ваш виртуальный помощник, для начала работы напишите "Включить"')

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def main(message):       
if message.chat.type == "private":
    if message.text == 'Включить':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте, сэр!')
    if message.text == 'Выключить':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Всего хорошего, до встречи!')
    if message.text == 'Монетка':
        coinflip(message)

def coinflip(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите "Подбросить", чтобы подбросить монетку и "Выход", чтобы выйти в главную часть')
    if message.text == 'Подбросить':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.randint(0, 1)
    elif message.text == 'Выход':
        main(message)
```

Хочу, чтобы после ввода 'Монетка', пользователя перекидывало в функцию coinflip. Там он подбрасывает сколько хочет, а потом после ввода 'Выход' его обратно отправляло в функцию main. Как отредактировать код, чтобы он работал именно так? (Неделю не могу найти решение)

Comment: Думаю вы должны использовать bot.register_next_step_handler вот пример использования https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Да, но в таком случае функция, на которую мы переходим, обрабатывает только одно сообщение от пользователя, а дальше программа продолжает выполнять предыдущую функцию. То есть мы пишем Монетка, заходим в coinfllip, функция обрабатывает 1 сообщение, а дальше снова начинает выполняться main. А хочется, чтобы пользователь писал Монетка, его перебрасывало в coinflip, там он писал Подбросить сколько угодно раз, потом он пишет Выход и он снова возвращается в main.

Comment: Тогда в функцию нужно добавить while True

Comment: Вообще посмотрите информацию по (Telegram Bot Games)